# Convert julian format dataseries to date?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, calendar, julian-date

This is a sample of my input data:

```
Julian_Day  number
1.337269    0.963173
1.396852    0.694848
1.40588     0.698301
1.47235     0.570787
1.474444    0.572122
1.476528    0.583249
1.482778    0.566614
1.489016    0.580695
1.49735     0.604001
1.514016    0.615488
1.516111    0.619653
1.539028    0.659143
1.543183    0.585216
1.603125    0.623025
1.605683    0.591181
1.607766    0.601155
1.609861    0.611359
1.611933    0.630703
1.614016    0.658801
```

I would like to convert the values in the `Julian_Day` column value to one of these date formats `01 Jan 2016` or `2016 01 0`.

I would like to create a plot using the converted date as the x-axis and the  corresponding value in the `number` column as the y-axis.

Here is the program so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import xlrd 
import openpyxl 
import datetime 
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

wb = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
z = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
for i in range(5,sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i+1, column=4).value
    z[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i+1, column=5).value

firstline = True
plt.xlabel('X values')
plt.ylabel('Y values')
plt.plot(x,y, 'bo-', label='V')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0,300)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.title('values')
plt.savefig('value1.png')
```

I am receiving this error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: That is *not* "the program so far," since you have left out import statements for `np` and `plt` and have not defined functions such as `load_workbook`. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the first time I am writing the question here. for the first part of the program:                              import xlrd, import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot. to be honest I am working on this small program more than 2 days. I am new at Python.

Comment: Which of those two last comments is correct? Never mind, you should go and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40621956/edit) to include the imports and other necessary declarations. Just make sure it is in the correct format--look at what I did to your code to see what that format is.

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: I  would like to convert Julian day format column to standard date time format of the year, e.g. 01 Jan 2016 or 2016 01 0. I need to show the new format the date in the x-axis. I tried for one day, but I can generalize for months or whole year since data expand up to one year. I also have the string data column as 2016-01-10 for a date, which is vice versa of Julian date. Nevertheless, when I run the program run, I have this message: float() argument must be a string or a number.  Any of these columns (Julian date or Date(dd-mm-yy) can be useful to add as x-axis

Comment: Trying to find a question amongst all the obscuring words.

Comment: Is the question unclear or codes? Anyway, all I need is to read the time (Julian) on the first column above and convert it to normal date.  I can do it on MATLAB but I can not find the similar codes working on python  2.7.2. Thanks in advance.